# Multiple Cameras - Fixed: Random Rooms

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok, so I basically created a series of prefab rooms that include a camera in a fixed position for each room. I created a box collider for each camera isTrigger and made the collider the size of the room.

```
public Camera curCam; 
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        curCam.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    } // End of trigger check
} // End of TriggerEnter

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        curCam.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Now I can add each room camera to its room under curCam. However, the camera shuts off upon exit and doesn't turn back on in the next room.

Edit Update:
The problem seems to reside within the fact my cameras are disabled and don't produce a box collider in that state. What I need to know is how to keep all cameras enabled but not rendering. Perhaps a state of sleep? I can't find anything about it. Please offer links, suggestions, or code examples.

Comment: It's probably that they're being set to `null`. Are you saying that they properly have cameras in the prefab but when they are instantiated in game they turn to null?

Comment: I suspect what @Ruzihm said. It would be good to post the rest of the code in that script. That will help tell us what is causing the issue.

Comment: I'm guessing that AntonioTorro is putting instantiated cameras into prefabs and then getting errors when instantiating those prefabs doesn't keep those links. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/135209/how-to-store-references-to-scene-objects-in-prefabs/135221

Comment: @Ruzihm - I designed a room and created a camera for that room. Then turned it into a prefab. I have the camera in the "Start room" set to active from Awake(). The rest of the cameras are .enabled = false; However, I just unchecked and disabled the extra cameras inside of unity. I want to set their active status upon trigger. If I must post the trigger enter and exit code, I will. There's exactly one line of code inside: .enabled / .disabled.

Comment: @Programmer - I added the code and I updated my post to what I'm now doing. The cameras stay inside of the variable now. I'm close here! However, camera shuts off, but won't turn back on. What happened?

Comment: Is this script attached *to* the camera?

Comment: @Draco18s Yes sir, the script is attached to the cameras. Once I leave through the start point room doorway and OnTriggerExit() executes, the camera shuts off and the next room collider doesn't initiate OnTriggerEnter(). I've tried to space the colliders apart and move them to nearly touching. Nothing seems to work. I'm curious as to what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Your script is attached to the (disabled) camera

Scripts attached to disabled game objects do not execute code. Any given script can never re-enable itself.

Comment: This is currently the problem. I put a box collider on the cameras, but since the're disabled, the box collider does too. I tried to get around this by adding an empty and putting the script on that rather than the cameras. However, this only adds a new camera to the scene. Same thing when I tried adding a cube for the trigger. Add the script and BOOM! Another camera appears... Annoying! So I guess, is there a way to keep the cameras enabled and them not render?

Comment: Disable the camera component instead of the game object.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]
```

I had attached this to my script the other night and forgot about it. I didn't grasp what its purpose was, but I thought it would help because I do require a camera. After looking into it, I removed this and my code works fine now.

Here's the solution:

```
public Camera curCam; 
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
if (other.tag == "Player")
{
    curCam.gameObject.SetActive(true);
} // End of trigger check
} // End of TriggerEnter

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
if (other.tag == "Player")
{
    curCam.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
}
```

Attach the script to a cube set in front of the doorways. Put the proper camera inserted into the inspector in each room. Code works perfectly!